# how to understand the Javascript code below

Tags: javascript

I study JavaScript and can you explain me code, please
The task is determine the max value in 4 arrays

```js
const myArr = [
  [4, 5, 1, 3],
  [13, 27, 18, 26],
  [32, 35, 37, 39],
  [1000, 1001, 857, 1]
];

function largestOfFour(arr) {
  let results = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    let largestNumber = arr[i][0];
    for (let j = 1; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
      if (arr[i][j] > largestNumber) {
        largestNumber = arr[i][j];
      }
    }
    results[i] = largestNumber;
  }

  return results;
}

console.log(largestOfFour(myArr));
```

So, first, we create the empty let for our future array? Then for cycle and i compare with the first item in the first array (number 4), right? and what mean arr[i][0]? What is the second for cycle do (with j)? Can you explain code on every row, please?

Comment: Work through JavaScript tutorial of your choice on operations with array elements.

Comment: Why don't you inspect the value of the variables at each line and discover what's going on yourself?

Comment: Here's an [An Introduction to Multidimensional Arrays in JavaScript](https://coding.degree/multidimensional-arrays-javascript-tutorial/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope the below helps. I've added comments.

```
function largestOfFour(arr) {
    // Initialize results to send back
    let results = [];
    // Go through all the arrays in the input 2-D array
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        // Assume largest number is first number of array
        let largestNumber = arr[i][0];
        // Go through rest of the numbers in the array
        for (let j = 1; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
            // If you find a larger number, update the largestNumber variable to that number. Basically, you are tracking the largest number in this array. 
            if (arr[i][j] > largestNumber) {
                largestNumber = arr[i][j];
            }
        }
        // The single array has been processed. Update the result with largest number found
        results[i] = largestNumber;
    }
    // Send the results. It is a 1-D array with the largest element of each of the input arrays
    return results;
}
```

The answer to your example is:

```
[ 5, 27, 39, 1001 ]

=== Verification ===
5 is largest element in [4, 5, 1, 3].
27 is largest element in [13, 27, 18, 26].
39 is largest element in [32, 35, 37, 39].
1001 is largest element in [1000, 1001, 857, 1].
```

Answer (score 0):

If you hadn't noticed `myArr` is a 2 dimensional array i. e. an array of arrays.

The first `for` loop ( using `i`) is looping through the outer array and the second `for` loop ( using `j`) is looping through the inner array.

What the function is doing is for each 'row' of the outer array, find the largest element in that row and assign it to appropriate index of `results` array.

Return `results` at the end.

Let me know if anything else is not clear.